# Генерация больших (64 битных и 128 битных) случайных чисел

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Как можно реализовать генерацию больших случайных чисел?

С помощью встроенных функций rand и srand генерируются значения только до 32 тысяч.

Я бы хотел сгенерировать числа вплоть до миллиардов.

Comment: `std::mt19937_64` генерирует 64 рандомных бита за раз. Для 128 - вызываете дважды.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а как это реализовать?

Comment: @David, использовать библиотеки для длинной арифметики. Либо хранить отдельно просто, в структуре запечатать можно. А вообще, если в системе есть 128 битный тип, то просто битовым сдвигом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всего лишь?

Миллиард вполне влазит в `int`. В `long long` поместится несколько миллиардов миллиардов - для стандартной библиотеки это нормальная штатная работа...

Стандартная библиотека [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) вам в помощь.

Но даже если вы не хотите пользоваться стандартом C++11, то на помощь вам придет Кнут - вот пара генераторов, которые я писал давно-давно (когда библиотека давала только `rand()`) по Кнуту (простите, алгоритм переписывать не буду, смотрите в книгах):

```
class Random
{
public:
    typedef int RandomValue;
    Random& operator = (int seed) { X = seed; return *this; }
    Random(int seed = 1):X(seed){};
    int operator()(int seed = 0)
    {
        const int MM = 2147483647;
        const int AA =      48271;
        const int QQ =      44488;
        const int RR =       3399;
        if (seed != 0) X = seed;
        X = AA*(X%QQ)-RR*(X/QQ);
        if (X < 0) X += MM;
        return X-1;
    }
    // Не включая max
    int operator()(int min, int max)
    {
        return (*this)()%(max-min) + min;
    }
private:
    int X;
};

class Random64
{
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
public:
    typedef uint64 RandomValue;
    Random64& operator = (uint64 seed) { X = seed; return *this; }
    Random64(uint64 seed = 0):X(seed){};
    uint64 operator()(uint64 seed = uint64(-1))
    {
        const uint64 a = 3202034522624059733ULL;
        const uint64 c =                   1ULL;

        if (seed != uint64(-1)) X = seed;
        uint64 Y = a * X + c;
        X = a * Y + c;
        Y = (Y&0xFFFFFFFF00000000ULL) | (X >> 32);
        return Y;
    }
    // Не включая max
    uint64 operator()(uint64 min, uint64 max)
    {
        return (*this)()%(max-min) + min;
    }
private:
    uint64 X;
};
```

Вот [пример работы](https://ideone.com/qQDy6V).

Comment: а можно этот код как - то сократить?

Comment: А зачем? его очень просто использовать - скажем, `Random64 r;` Если хочется - `Random64 r(time(0));` И все. Дальше случайное число - `r()`. Или число в диапазоне от 0 до 100 - `r(0,100)`. Зачем что-то сокращать? Сам алгоритм - так точно не надо :)

Comment: Я сейчас попытался протестировать, действительно генерируется всё, но не полностью случайные или может я что - то неправильно понял. При повторном запуске программы генерируются те же числа, что при первом запуске программы, почему так?

Comment: Seed не используете. Вы когда `rand()` запускаете - то же самое, если только `srand()` не выполните. Здесь `srand()` по сути внесен в конструктор - создавайте генератор, например, как я написал, как `Random64 r(time(0));`

Comment: Такая тут себе энтропия....

Comment: @Andrey Претензии по адресу taocp@cs.stanford.edu... Кстати, имеете даже шанс заработать :) - Кнут честно платит за исправления...

Comment: @Harry а как задействовать seed?

Comment: *Третий* раз пишу - `Random64 r(time(0));`

Comment: @Harry понял, всё работает, спасибо. А как можно настроить диапазон? Я попытался понять данный код, но к сожалению полностью его не осилил, мне не все строчки ясны

Comment: Ну просто указываете при вызове `r(min,max)`.

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас есть готовый генератор чисел длиной `n` битов, то получить из него генератор более длинных чисел вы можете обычной конкатенацией битовых последовательностей, полученных из последовательных вызовов имеющегося генератора.

В своем вопросе вы упомянули генератор, генерирующий 15 псевдослучайных битов. Пять вызовов такого генератора дадут вам 64-битное псевдослучайное число

```
uint64_t rand64 = ((((((((uint64_t) rand() << 15) + rand()) << 15) + rand()) << 15) + rand()) << 15) + rand();
```

"Лишние" биты, если таковые имеются, вы можете просто выбросить (как я сделал выше), а можете сохранить для следующего длинного числа.

Разумеется, бесплатных завтраков не бывает. Раз размер внутреннего состояния генератора остался неизменным, а генерируемые числа стали длиннее, значит где-то в другом месте что-то стало "короче". А именно: короче в соответствующее количество раз стал период такого генератора. Критично вам это или не критично - зависит от вашего приложения.

Comment: В этом случае не будет "хороших" псевдослучайных чисел, так как будет большая алгоритмическая компонента.

Comment: Хм.. Я почти так же написал, но у меня последний не `rand()`, а `rand()&15`.

Comment: @becouse: В таком варианте числа настолько же хороши, насколько хорош сам генератор. Платите вы за это, однако, кратным сокращением периода генератора.

Comment: Кстати, тип же привести надо, а то он всё равно под 32 бита подрежется.

Comment: @AnT об этом и речь, что вы не получаете новую случайную последовательность из существующих, она будет все менее и менее случайной при каждой операции. Если бы этот способ работал никто бы не изобретал новые генераторы)

Comment: @becouse: Чего? С чего бы это вдруг она будет "все менее и менее случайной"? Нет, конечно, не будет. И никакие "новые генераторы" для области применения уровня обычного `rand()` никто не изобретает, а делают именно так, как я показал выше.

Comment: @AnT так уже лет 20 не делают....

Comment: @Andrey: Наоборот, делают именно и только так. Других способов просто не существует. Все виды случайных величин на практике получают путем трансформации одного или нескольких результатов равномерно распределенного генератора. То, что я привел выше - лишь один частный пример такой трансформации.

Comment: @AnT ну а как же диоды Зенера. Квантовые-лазерные сервера энтропии и тд? и вопрос seed тут где?

Comment: @Andrey: Это не более чем способ организации подлежащего равномерно распределенного первичного генератора. Тот самый `std::random_device`. А дальше начинается тернистый путь от этого первичного генератора до [псевдо]случайного числа в ваших руках, т.е. именно та трансформация, один из частных примеров которой я показал выше.

Comment: @AnT да обработка сида - наше все

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример генерации для unsigned long long

```
 //Источник
  std::random_device rd;

  //Генератор
  std::default_random_engine generator(rd());

  // Распределение
  std::uniform_int_distribution<long long unsigned> distribution(0,0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);

  //Десять длинных случайных чисел
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      std::cout << distribution(generator) << std::endl;
  }
```

Также вы можете посмотреть на [клеточный автомат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_30) Стивена Вольфрама, который позволяет получать сколь угодно большие собственно случайные последовательности нулей и единиц и используется в Wolfram Mathematica для генерации случайных чисел.

Он не сложный и можно пробовать его реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас Linux читайте /dev/urandom нормальный такой ПДСЧ

Если win юзайте mt

Вот пример 4 перегрузок функции для генерации данный с ПДСЧ

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>


template<typename T>
void get_entropy(T* ptr, const std::size_t size) {
    if (ptr == nullptr || size == 0) {
        return;
    }

#ifdef __linux__
    static std::string urandom_path{ "/dev/urandom" };
    std::fstream urandom_stream(urandom_path.c_str(), std::fstream::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!urandom_stream.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error{ "Error : Cannot open file " + urandom_path };
    }
    urandom_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr), sizeof(T)* size);
    urandom_stream.close();
#endif // __linux__

#ifdef _WIN32
    static std::random_device rand_dev{};
    static std::mt19937_64 generator(rand_dev());
    auto data_size{sizeof(T) * size};
    uint64_t rand_value{0};
    while (data_size) {
        auto step_copy_size{data_size <= sizeof(rand_value) ? data_size
                                                            : sizeof(uint64_t)};
        rand_value = generator();
        std::memcpy(ptr, &rand_value, step_copy_size);
        ++ptr;
        data_size -= step_copy_size;
    }
#endif // _WIN32
}


template<typename T>
T get_entropy() {
    T ret{};
    get_entropy<T>(&ret, 1);
    return ret;
}


template<typename T>
void get_entropy(T* ptr) {
    if (ptr == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    get_entropy<T>(ptr, sizeof(T));
}


template<typename T>
void get_entropy(T* begin_ptr, T* end_ptr) {
    if (begin_ptr == nullptr || end_ptr == 0) {
        return;
    }
    auto size{ end_ptr - begin_ptr };
    if (!size) {
        return;
    }
    if (size < 0) {
        get_entropy<T>(end_ptr, std::abs(size));
        return;
    }
    get_entropy<T>(begin_ptr, size);
}



template<typename T>
T entripy_distribution(T val, T low, T height) {
    low = std::min(low, height);
    height = std::max(low, height);
    ++height;
    --low;

    T dist{ height - low - 1 };

    if (val < low) {
        auto x{ low - val };
        x = x / (dist);
        val += (x + 1) * (dist);
    }

    if (val > height) {
        auto x{ val - height };
        x = x / (dist);
        val -= (x + 1) * (dist);
    }

    return val;
}


struct s
{
    s() :a(0), b(0) {}
    uint64_t a;
    uint64_t b;

    void print() {
        std::cout << "a :" << this->a << " b : " << this->b << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {

    std::ostream_iterator<uint64_t> stdout_it{ std::cout, "\n" };

    std::cout << "Gen singl value v1 no args: " << std::endl;

    for (auto i{ 0 }; i < 10; ++i) {
        stdout_it = entripy_distribution<uint64_t>(get_entropy<uint64_t>(), 1'000'000'000, 2'000'000'000);
    }


    std::cout << "Gen singl value v2 ptr: " << std::endl;
    uint64_t val{ 0 };
    for (auto i{ 0 }; i < 10; ++i) {
        get_entropy<uint64_t>(&val);
        stdout_it = val;
    }

    std::cout << "Gen singl value v3 ptr + size: " << std::endl;

    for (auto i{ 0 }; i < 10; ++i) {
        get_entropy<uint64_t>(&val, sizeof(val));
        stdout_it = val;
    }

    std::cout << "Gen singl value v4 ptr + ptr: " << std::endl;

    for (auto i{ 0 }; i < 10; ++i) {
        get_entropy<uint64_t>(&val, &val + sizeof(val));
        stdout_it = val;
    }

    std::cout << "Gen array v1: no args" << std::endl;
    std::vector<uint64_t> v(10);
    get_entropy<uint64_t>(v.data(), v.size());
    for (const auto& val : v) {
        stdout_it = val;
    }

    std::cout << "Gen array v2: ptr " << std::endl;
    std::vector<uint64_t> v2(10);
    auto f{ []() {return entripy_distribution<uint64_t>(get_entropy<uint64_t>(), 0, 10); } };
    std::generate(std::begin(v2), std::end(v2), f);
    for (const auto& val : v2) {
        stdout_it = val;
    }

    std::cout << "Gen array v3: ptr + size " << std::endl;
    auto arr_size{ 10 };
    uint64_t* arr = new uint64_t[arr_size];
    get_entropy<uint64_t>(arr, arr_size);
    for (auto i{ 1 }; i < arr_size; ++i) {
        stdout_it = arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;

    std::cout << "Gen array v4: ptr + ptr " << std::endl;
    std::vector<uint64_t> v3(10);
    uint64_t* arr2 = new uint64_t[arr_size];
    get_entropy<uint64_t>(&(*(std::begin(v3))) + v3.size(), &(*(std::begin(v3))));
    for (const auto& val : v3) {
        stdout_it = val;
    }

    s obj{};
    get_entropy<char>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&obj), sizeof(obj));
    obj.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В такой реализации `get_entropy_mt` генератор выполняет в 8 раз больше работы, чем нужно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, но я воткнул что было под рукой )))

Comment: @HolyBlackCat теперь все норм)

Comment: Для `sizeof(T) > sizeof(uint64_t)` ничего не поменялось. :) Да и новый `std::mt19937_64` создавать при каждом вызове - не комильфо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Будет время перепишем) По поводу размера больше - тоже )))) спасибо за ревью)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну а так?

Answer (score 0):

```
((((((((unsigned long long)rand() << 15) | rand()) << 15) | rand()) << 15) | rand()) << 4) | (rand() & 15)
```